# What does "with him" mean in 2 Corinthians 6?

Tags: translation-philosophy, 2-corinthians

(KJV)2 Corinthians 6:1

> We then, as workers together **with him** , beseech you also that ye receive not the grace of God in vain.

Why does Paul use "with him" does this mean that the apostle Paul & ministers were joint- labourers with God in securing the reconciliation of the world to himself or was Paul teaching that he was a joint- worker with God in securing the salvation of the people

Comment: The phrase “with him” is not present in the Greek text but is supplied by the editors of the KJV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The literal Greek - συνεργουντες - just says "working together", without any pronoun.

In any case, in his [*12th Homily on 2 Corinthians*](https://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf112.v.xii.html), John Chrysostom admits both interpretations.  In the sense of working with others:

> And working together we intreat also. Working together with you; 'for
>   we work together with you, rather than with God for Whom we are
>   ambassadors. For He is in need of nothing, but the salvation all
>   passes over to you.'

In the sense of working with God, he recalls 1 Corinthians 3:9:

> But if it is even with God that he speaks of working together, he
>   repudiates not even this [interpretation]; for he says in another
>   place, *we are God's fellow-workers*: in this way, says he, to save
>   men.